# Dovecot: Import from /var/spool/mail mbox to ~/Maildir

Tags: email-server, dovecot

I've just migrated a personal mailserver from Courier MTA setup to a Postfix/Dovecot one.  I thought I had it all worked out, but after I updated the MX record I realized Postfix was dumping mail into `/var/spool/mail` instead of it being transferred via dovecot, which was remedied by setting up LMTP as the transfer mechanism.

Now I need to put the contents of the `/var/spool/mail` mbox into the (non-virtual) user's `~/Maildir` maildir. Unfortunately, I'm a bit flummoxed by the syntax of `doveadm sync/backup`.  My latest attempt looks like this (the username is `email`):

```
doveadm -Dv -o mail_location=mbox:/home/email/tmp:INBOX=/var/spool/mail/email \
   sync -u email -1 maildir:/home/email/Maildir
```

This was run by the email user, and `/home/email/tmp` was empty and owned by same. I had to chown 600 `/var/spool/mail/email` [because of this](https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/errors/chgrp_no_perm/).  Now the problem is:

```
Error: Mail locations must use the same hierarchy separator (specify namespace prefix="" { separator } explicitly)
```

I've searched around about that and it appears to me that this has to be set in a conf file, but I'm not sure where to start, or whether it will solve the problem -- if "mail locations must use **the same** hierarchy separator", and the maildir one is `.`, changing it will presumably then cause a problem with the maildir...

And at this point I feel like I'm having to learn to fly a helicopter so I can pick up some groceries down the street.